# Can I reuse a struct field during type conversion without calling .clone()?

Tags: rust, type-conversion, clone, move, borrow-checker

I currently have two similar structs, and I need to implement the `From` trait to convert one to the other. However, I'm getting an error that says:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `item.my_first_string`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:30
   |
13 |             my_second_string: item.my_first_string,
   |                               -------------------- value moved here
14 |             string_is_empty: item.my_first_string.is_empty(),
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `item.my_first_string` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Here's what my code looks like:

```rust
struct Foo {
    my_first_string: String,
}

struct Bar {
    my_second_string: String,
    string_is_empty: bool,
}

impl From<Foo> for Bar {
    fn from(item: Foo) -> Self {
        Bar {
            my_second_string: item.my_first_string,
            string_is_empty: item.my_first_string.is_empty(),
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware that I could just call `.clone` on `my_first_string` to satisfy the borrow checker, but this seems like it may be unnecessary. Is there a way to use this field twice without `.clone()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store the result of `is_empty()` is a variable before moving the string:

```rust
impl From<Foo> for Bar {
    fn from(item: Foo) -> Self {
        let string_is_empty = item.my_first_string.is_empty();
        Bar {
            my_second_string: item.my_first_string,
            string_is_empty,
        }
    }
}
```

Or just inverse the order:

```rust
impl From<Foo> for Bar {
    fn from(item: Foo) -> Self {
        Bar {
            string_is_empty: item.my_first_string.is_empty(),
            my_second_string: item.my_first_string,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by like 15 seconds!  Grr! - That being said, make sure to emphasize that they're doing a move, and that they intend to, though using `From` that's required, but still.

Comment: The first keep the order, the second is shorter. Which is better or more commonly use? (Or it is opinion based?)

Comment: @cpprust Opinion based.